# how do I display the same data and aggregate it in one line in yii2?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app, yii2-model

[image]

MODEL

```
public function getJumlah()
{
    return $this->hasMany(AssetMaster::className(), ['id_asset_received' => 'received_date'])
        ->leftJoin('asset_received','asset_received.id_asset_received = asset_master.id_asset_master')
        ->groupBy('received_date')
        ->count();
}
```

VIEW

```
<?= GridView::widget(
[
    'behaviors' => [
        [
            'class' => '\dosamigos\grid\behaviors\GroupColumnsBehavior',
            'extraRowColumns' => ['assetMaster.asset_name'],
            'extraRowValue' => function($model, $key, $index, $totals) {
                return '<span class="label label-warning">' . $model['received_year'] . '</span>';
            },
            'mergeColumns' => ['assetMaster.asset_name','received_year']
        ]

    ],

    'columns' => [
           'assetMaster.asset_name',
```

`received_date',
               'received_year',
            'Jumlah'
            ],
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'layout' => "\n{items}\n{pager}"
    ]
);
?>`  '

i want sum "nama barang " every search i use , for now "jumlah" is the result of COUNT
and make it into just one line, is there anyone who can help

Comment: You can use anoymous functipns for colum values in DataColums inside Gridviews: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-grid-datacolumn#$value-detail. Maybe this is the easiest way but not the fastest.

Comment: @muhammad use `sum` instead of `count`

Comment: mention view content in your question

Comment: apart from everything if you are concerned about the count only i would suggest using `yii\db\Query` rather than `yii\db\ActiveRecord`